# show progress bar when pushing using git

Tags: git, git-push

I'm trying to push a large file to a `git` repository using `git push -u origin master` but it is failing on the half way. It would be of great help if I can see when it fails. Is there a way to show something like a progress bar in `git push`?

**Edit:** Doing some brute force I was able to push the file at last on my 7th or 8th trial but I'm still curious about the question.

Comment: I don't know, but if you have a proxy server between your computer and the git repo, I bet that the proxy rejects uploads of larger that X bytes (maybe 1mb?). If you have access to that proxy, check the logs, there should be something there. You can also set the environment variable `GIT_TRACE=1` to get more detailed information.

Comment: well, the repo is in `bitbucket` so there's probably a proxy server in between. Is there a way to access those servers?

Comment: mmm strange, bitbucket doesn't put size limits :S.

Comment: just to be clear we're talking about 200MB+

Answer (score 3):

```
git push -v origin
```

Tells me enough to go.